# Computing 2 independent matrix-vector multiplications with OpenMP tasks is slower than processing each one in turn

Tags: multithreading, matrix, task, openmp, matrix-multiplication

I am computing the matrix vector product of two different matrices. I.e. I need to compute `A*v` and `B*v`. I am seeing speedup by using thread and vector level parallelism. I have noticed that, for the matrix sizes I have tested, the speedup curve flattens out after ~8 threads (for appropriately large matrix sizes). As I am on a 16 thread machine, I thought it natural to throw another 4 or 5 threads at the other matrix-vector multiplication and compute both at the same time by assigning each to a task. However, as the problem size increases, computing with tasks in this thread range is consistently worse than computing without. See the figure below. This is not intuitive to me, I would have expected tasks to be out performing the sequential function calls.

[image: Matrix-vector multiplication speedup]

```c
    // This is consistently worse
    #pragma omp task
    matrixVectorMultiplicationParallel(A,  V, resultsA, matrixSize, numThreads/2);
    #pragma omp task
    matrixVectorMultiplicationParallel(B, V, resultsB, matrixSize, numThreads/2);
    #pragma omp taskwait
```

```c
    // this is consistently better (this is corresponds to the blue line in the figures)
    matrixVectorMultiplicationParallel(A, V, resultsA, matrixSize, numThreads);
    matrixVectorMultiplicationParallel(B, V, resultsB, matrixSize, numThreads);
```

Have I misunderstood some aspect of tasking, or is this simply the overhead of creating tasks exceeding their usefulness here? Why, for instance, is computing `A*v` and `B*v` with 5 threads each at the same time (10 threads total) equal to computing `A*v` then `B*v`

This is being used as part of a larger recursive algorithm, in which each recusive call computes a matrix-vector multiplication on smaller and smaller matrices.

Full code:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define THREAD_RANGE 16 // Run for 1:THREAD_RANGE threads
#define NUM_AVERAGES 10 // take the average of 5 timings for each matrix size, and each number of threads
#define MATRIX_SIZE  3000 

// gcc -fopenmp matrix_tasking.c -o matrix_tasking -O3 -Wall -Werror
double parallelTimings[THREAD_RANGE];

void matrixVectorMultiplicationSequential(double *restrict M, double *restrict V, double *restrict results,  unsigned long matrixSize)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
    {
        double *MHead = &M[i * matrixSize];
        double tmp = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++)
        {
            tmp += MHead[j] * V[j];
        }
        results[i] = tmp;
    }
}


void matrixVectorMultiplicationParallel(double *restrict M, double *restrict V, double *restrict results, unsigned long matrixSize, int numThreads)
{
    omp_set_num_threads(numThreads);
    unsigned long i, j;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(j)
    for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
    {
        double tmp = 0;
        double *MHead = &M[i * matrixSize];

        #pragma omp simd reduction(+ \
                          : tmp)
        for (j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++)
        {
            tmp += MHead[j] * V[j];
        }
        results[i] = tmp; 
    }
}

void doParallelComputation(double *restrict A, double *restrict B, double *restrict V, double *restrict resultsA, double *restrict resultsB, unsigned long matrixSize, int numThreads)
{
    #pragma omp task
    matrixVectorMultiplicationParallel(A,  V, resultsA, matrixSize, numThreads/2);
    #pragma omp task
    matrixVectorMultiplicationParallel(B, V, resultsB, matrixSize, numThreads/2);
    #pragma omp taskwait
}

void genRandVector(double *S, unsigned long size)
{
    srand(time(0));
    unsigned long i;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        double n = rand() % 3;
        S[i] = n;
    }
}

void doSequentialComputation(double *restrict A, double *restrict B, double *restrict V, double *restrict resultsA, double *restrict resultsB, unsigned long matrixSize)
{
    matrixVectorMultiplicationSequential(A, V, resultsA, matrixSize);
    matrixVectorMultiplicationSequential(B, V, resultsB, matrixSize);
}


void genRandMatrix(double *A, unsigned long size)
{
    srand(time(0));
    unsigned long i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            double n = rand() % 3;
            A[i * size + j] = n;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timespec start, finish;
    double elapsed;

    unsigned long matrixSize = 100;

    double *V = (double *)malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(double));
    double *seqVA = (double *)malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(double)); // Store the results of A*v in the sequential implementation here
    double *parVA = (double *)malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(double)); // Store the results of A*v in the parallel implementation here
    double *seqVB = (double *)malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(double)); // Store the results of B*v in the sequential implementation here
    double *parVB = (double *)malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(double)); // Store the results of B*v in the parallel implementation here
    double *A = (double *)malloc(matrixSize * matrixSize * sizeof(double)); // First matrix to multiply by V
    double *B = (double *)malloc(matrixSize * matrixSize * sizeof(double)); // Second matrix to multiply by V

    genRandVector(V, matrixSize);
    genRandMatrix(A, matrixSize);
    genRandMatrix(B, matrixSize);
    double sequentialTiming = 0;
    
    for (int a = 0; a < NUM_AVERAGES; a++)
    {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
        doSequentialComputation(A, B, V, seqVA, seqVB, matrixSize);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
        elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
        elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
        sequentialTiming += elapsed;
        for (int t = 1; t <= THREAD_RANGE; t++)
        {
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
            omp_set_num_threads(t);

            #pragma omp parallel 
            {
                #pragma omp single 
                doParallelComputation(A, B, V, parVA, parVB, matrixSize, t);
            }
                // doParallelComputation(A, B, V, parVA, parVB, matrixSize, t);

            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
            elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
            elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
            parallelTimings[t - 1] += elapsed;

            // parallelTiming += elapsed;
            for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
            {
                assert(fabs(seqVA[i] - parVA[i]) < 0.01);
            }
            
        }
    }
    sequentialTiming /= NUM_AVERAGES;

    printf("Sequential: %f \n", sequentialTiming);
    printf("Parallel: ");

    for (int t = 0; t < THREAD_RANGE; t++)
    {
        parallelTimings[t] /= NUM_AVERAGES;
        printf("%f ", parallelTimings[t]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(seqVA);
    free(parVA);
    free(seqVB);
    free(parVB);
    free(A);
    free(V);
    free(B);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to declare `tmp` as a reduction variable, as each thread operates on separate rows and thus separate `i` indices.

Comment: For synchronisation that is true, but it appears that `gcc` needs the reduction clause to properly vectorise the subsequent code (that is, it needs it with the compiler flags I provided in the source code). See here: https://godbolt.org/z/aP4dnT (I think this might not be necessary if you specify the target architecture appropriately in the compiler flags though)

Comment: @Cimbali that's horizontal SIMD reduction, not reduction of per-thread values

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the answers lie in the hardware, not so much in the thread or task level.

First, you say you have 16 threads, but are they [hyperthreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) ? By that I mean, do you have in fact 8 cores or 16 cores in your CPU ? Because such threads are meant to increase the utilisation of common resources in a core, such as FPUs. But if these are already saturated, then adding more threads does not increase the number of operations your machine can perform.

That would answer why your performance flattens at 8 threads, and thus also why adding more parallelism (ie two multiplications simultaneously) doesn’t further accelerate things.

Second, I think the rest of the difference, especially in large vector sizes, might be up to caches and/or memory bandwidth:
for each row result (ie each inner loop on `j`), you need the full input vector and a full row of the matrix. If all threads are executing the same multiplication, the they use the same input vector.

This means more pressure on cache and more memory bandwidth required to sustain computation if you’re computing both multiplications at the same time, and those are both finite resources. To see which is the real bottleneck you’d need to run some profiling.

So the effect you’re seeing could be due to:

- same utilisation of computing resources, contrarily to what you’re suspecting,
- less efficient utilisation of caches and memory bandwidth

Comment: Host machine is an i7-9700k, so 8 logical processors. Cache blocking is on the todo, i'll update when I test with it. I'll also try some cache profiling.

Comment: @daviegravee the [reference sheet](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/186604/intel-core-i7-9700k-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html) even says 8 cores and 8 threads, not 16 threads.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do this at all!**

Use the appropriate BLAS routine which will already be parallelised, vectorised, cache-blocked, and portable to the next machine you happen to run on.
See, for instance, [LAPACK dgemv](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d15/group__double__blas__level2_gadd421a107a488d524859b4a64c1901a9.html) and then consider which of the many BLAS libraries (LAPACK, MKL, ...) you want to use.

Comment: Don't worry, this isn't going into production. This is entirely for academic purposes (and curiosity).